# How to run two non-terminating scripts in parallel in a GUI?

Tags: python, ssh, tkinter, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-14.04

I know I can easily do this manually by opening two terminal windows. I am trying to automate the process as much as possible by creating a GUI with two buttons. One to connect and run the listener, and one to run the talker.

This is my code:

```
#python 3
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk

#python 2
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

import time
import subprocess
import paramiko

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass


def connect():
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect('192.168.1.2', username='pi', password='raspberry')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('roscore &')
  time.sleep(20)
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('\n')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd scripts')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/pi/scripts/listener2.py')
  return

def run():
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python ES96_Vivaldi/talker2.py')


root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Connect", command=connect).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=S)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Run", command=run).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Click 'Connect' to establish link.").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Click 'Run' to control using the arrow keys").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

It opens a small GUI with a Connect button and a Run button. Connect works fine but since the listener2.py script doesn't terminate, the GUI freezes and I can't press the Run button (same problem when trying in the opposite order).

Is there a way to start a script and leave it running in the background so that the GUI isn't frozen and I can start the next script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the handlers in background threads. In your current setup, the handlers don't give any feedback to the gui, so its really just a matter of switching the button commands to functions that start the threads.

I added a bit of code to disable the buttons so the handlers can only be started once. The trick there is that you need some place to store the button widgets so that you can access them again later.

```
#python 3
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk

#python 2
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

import time
import subprocess
import paramiko

import threading

# keep track of widgets for event handlers
widget_track = {}

# event handler creates connect thread
def connect_evt():
    t = threading.Thread(target=connect)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    widget_track['connect'].config(text="Connected", state="disabled", command=None)

def connect():
  time.sleep(5)   # todo: temporary for test
  return
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect('192.168.1.2', username='pi', password='raspberry')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('roscore &')
  time.sleep(20)
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('\n')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd scripts')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/pi/scripts/listener2.py')
  return

# event handler creates run thread
def run_evt():
    t = threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    widget_track['run'].config(text="Running", state="disabled", command=None)

def run():
  time.sleep(5)     # todo: temporary for test
  return
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python ES96_Vivaldi/talker2.py')


root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# connect button starts connect background thread
btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Connect", command=connect_evt)
btn.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=S)
widget_track['connect'] = btn

# run button start run background thread
btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Run", command=run_evt)
btn.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)
widget_track['run'] = btn

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Click 'Connect' to establish link.").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Click 'Run' to control using the arrow keys").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```